# How can I equalize the size of those two matrices in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, equality

I have the following two matrices with the sizes shown:

```
x ---> 256x256

y ---> 65536x2
```

How can we equalize the sizes of those two matrices? In other words, how can we make size `y` equal size `x`? I know we can use `padarray`. But, how can we use it here? Wouldn't some information get lost from this equalization?

Thanks.

Comment: btw please don not ask the same question 1E16 times

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to [Reshape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html). If you need help with it. Provide more informations of what you want to do.

```
y = reshape(y,256,256);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that and got the following error: `>>y=reshape(y,256,256)
??? Error using ==> reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.` Why is that? Thanks

Comment: because `256*256 = 65536`, whereas `y` has twice the number of elements.

Comment: My mistake, 256x256 = 65536. But i didn`t see the x2. So your matrix y is twice bigger than the x. So you have to fit those function with your problem. Explain what you want to do or read the documentation I provide or read Starting guide of MatLab.

Answer (score 0):

Use `reshape` function then:

```
reshape(y,size(x))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just get the size of `y` here and not the size of `x`...